# How to get custom image attribute into header

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom, product-images

I have created an attribute for image as "custom_image" to show it in the in the header for every product.

I have get the base_image with the following code:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product);
$product_image = $product->getImageUrl();
```

Now i want to get the custom_image and i have tried it like:

```
 $product_image = $product->getImageUrl(custom_image);
```

but it is not working kindly guide me what wrong i am doing and how i can get the custom image attribute.

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code

```
$product_imag=str_replace('/index.php', '',Mage::getUrl('media/catalog/product').$product->getCustomImage());
```

Comment: if i want to get the URL of this image then? @Gopal Patel

Comment: It is just showing /p/1/p12-carrar24_2.jpg this thing i need the full URL how i can get that?  @Gopal Patel

Comment: @Xabby find updated answer

Comment: I did its going to 404 page not image found: http://usatilea.nextmp.net/index.php/media/catalog/product/p/1/p12-carrar24_2.jpg

Comment: @Xabby make sure that image is present at that location

Comment: it is present on this URL : http://usatilea.nextmp.net/media/catalog/product/p/1/p12-carrar24_2.jpg

Comment: @Xabby now try updated answer

Comment: @Xabby issue is due to index.php. just unable SEO rewrite on production system->general->web->SEO

Comment: i am using it on all over the site so cant get rid of it at this stage

Comment: One more question.. how i can exclude this custom image to now show on product page? @Gopal Patel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51170/discussion-between-xabby-and-gopal-patel).